# Ajax to return partial view, losing JavaScript functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'll update this with a few code examples when I can but I'm just looking for some general advice that anyone might have.

I have a ASP.Net MVC site which makes use of partial views.  I have all my scripts in the BundleConfig file and they are loaded in the _Layout page.  I have  partial view that includes a bit of JavaScript related controls, DropZone and draggable divs etc.  Using Ajax, I call a method in my controller to load the partial view.  However when Ajax loads the partial view, I lose all Javascript functionality.

Is there a neater or more simple approach that I should adopt when using partial views that rely a lot on javascript?

Many thanks for any help!!

Comment: What do you mean by "losing Javascript functionality"? Does the script on the partial views not work, or scripts on the _Layout not work? Are you using jQuery?

Comment: post the code of your partial view

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, got it sorted.  I put the javascript in a function on the partial view and made a simple call to run all the js after the ajax return.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET MVC, if you want to execute JavaScript code each time a partial view gets rendered, you can use the ajaxComplete event to detect when an AJAX request (which is typically how partial views are loaded) is completed, and then run your JavaScript code accordingly.

Here's how you can do it:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
    // Check if the AJAX request is for loading the partial view
        // Your JavaScript code to run when the partial view is rendered
        console.log("Partial view rendered, executing JavaScript...");
        yourFunction(); // Call your function here, or put your code directly here
    }
});
```